# How to handle dynamic JSON response using retrofit2 in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I'm using retrofit2 in kotlin for rest API and get data from server but, every time API sent response has different, not same JSON data. I want to handle dynamic JSON object response. I don't know how to make it.

I created the data class for static JSON data but want dynamic.

```
data class GetDetails(
    var Id: String? = null,
    var UId: String? = null,
    var DOB: String? = null,
    var Name: String? = null,
    var Address: String? = null
)
```

handle the response using

```
requestCall.enqueue(object : Callback<List<GetDetails>> {

                override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<GetDetails>>, response: Response<List<GetDetails>>) {
...
})
```

I created a static data class but, I want to handle dynamic JSON object response. I mean when server API send the response with 4 JSON elements or 10 JSON elements or 20 JSON elements. I should have been able to handle it.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

> You can get response in json as JsonElement and then handle

```
@POST("function/ResizeImage?")
    fun resizeImage(@Query("AppGuid") guid:String,
                      @Query("UserAppGuid") uuid:String,
                      @Query("ImageUrl") imageUrl:String,
                      @Query("Width") width:String,
                    @Query("Height") height:String,
                    @Query("FileName") fileName:String,
                    @Query("FileType") fileType:String): Call<JsonElement>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just bad practice for one Model to handle a range 4 JSON elements to 20 JSON elements. But if you are going through with this, you will have to set all fields as nullable (if you don't have any mandatory), and check onResponse for each one if it's null when trying to access it.

Answer (score 0):

If your JSON response is changing dynamically, you can store the json as key-value pairs (Map< String,String >) and consume the keys known to you.

In kotlin, You can also have class delegated properties stored in map

[try link here](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Examples/Delegated%20properties/Properties%20in%20map/Properties%20in%20map.kt)

[Documentation here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html)